# Interpreting or utilizing k-means clusters from multidimensional data

Tags: data-visualization, k-means

K-means clusters can be calculated for multidimensional data--with 5 or 8 variables for instance--by minimizing the "within clusters sum of squares" (WCSS) just as you would for 2 or 3 dimension data. But at 5 or 8 dimensions the clusters become hard/impossible to visualize and interpret, so how are such high dimension clusters practically utilized or applied?

Comment: You don't have to visualize clusters to interpret them. As for visualization, please search this site `data visualization high dimensional` `data visualization k-means results`

Comment: @ttnphns, can you explain or point me towards resources for interpreting clusters without visualizing them?